# Finite intersections of a countable family of sets is countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{A} = \{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a countable family of sets. Is it true that the following set $$\mathcal{F}:=\{ B : B=\bigcap_{j=1}^n A_{a_j} \text{ for a finite choice of } A_{a_j} \text{ in } \mathcal{A} \}$$ is countable?

Comment: What have you done on this problem, and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you I've edited the title, now is correct.

Comment: Let $\mathcal F_2$ be the set where $n=2$. Is it countable? How about the set $\mathcal F_3$? Observe that $\mathcal F = \mathcal F_1 \cup \mathcal F_2 \cup \dots$

Answer (score 1):

> $\mathcal{F}$ is countable.

There is a surjective map $$\bigcup_n \mathcal{A}^n \to \mathcal{F},$$  in fact the correspondence $\{A_{a_1}, \dots, A_{a_n}  \}\mapsto \bigcap_1^n A_{a_j}$ is surjective; thus $$| \mathcal{F}| \leq |\bigcup_n \mathcal{A}^n| \leq | \sum_{n} \aleph_0 | \stackrel{1}{ =}  | \aleph_0 \times \aleph_0| = \aleph_0. $$

[1] A chessboard is the union of its rows.

---

Notice that $\bigcup_n \mathcal{A}^n$ is a proper subset of $\mathcal{A}^{\mathbb{N}}! $

Answer (score 0):

There is only one element of $\mathcal F$ for each $n$

Hint:  For the revised question, how many finite subsets of a countable set are there?

Comment: To the downvoter:  this was correct when the answer was posted.